# Rename datasets in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Could I request a feature to allow renaming datasets in BigQuery. I have a few datasets with 1000+ tables. I would like to rename the dataset without copying every single table.

Comment: I doubt this page is for feature requests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks for the feature request. There are a couple of reasons why this would be a difficult feature to add. One reason is that it couldn't be done atomically, given our current architecture. That would mean we'd have to move tables individually in the BigQuery server, which doesn't seem ideal.

One thing that we could add relatively easily, is an atomic table move function that moves your table from one dataset to another. This would save you the copy. Would that be helpful?

Either way, a better way to communicate feature requests is via the BigQuery public issue tracker here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list

Comment: Yes it will help. 

Thanks for the link. I'll make sure to post requests there next time.

Comment: Is there any update regarding this "rename datasets" feature? Will this ever be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot change the name of an existing dataset, and you cannot copy a dataset and give it a new name. If you need to change the dataset name, follow these steps to recreate the dataset:

1. Create a new dataset and specify the new name.
2. Copy the tables from the old dataset to the new one.
3. Recreate the views in the new dataset.
4. Delete the old dataset to avoid additional storage costs.

For more information check: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets